# How can I get the [Error]: from NSError.description?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nserror

I am trying to create a `UIAlertView` that displays only the error of `NSError.description`.

For example:

```
var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: error.description, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
alert.show()
```

Say the `error.description` outputs:

```
2015-02-01 02:26:43.227 UserLogin[249:13655] [Error]: missing username (Code: 200, Version: 1.6.2)
```

How can I just get the `[Error]: missing username` in a `String`? I am new to app development and I simply want my error messages to make sense to the user and to be simple.

If this does not make sense, I am using Parse and I am working on a registration form. If the error occurs such as *"missing username"*, *"username taken"*, etc. I just wanted to find a way to get a simple error popup to say *"username taken"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [localizedDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/localizedDescription) property of `NSError`.

Instead of `error.description` use `error.localizedDescription`

```
var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message: error.localizedDescription, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
alert.show()
```

**Note:**

[UIAlertView](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertView) is deprecated in iOS 8, use [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Try using this:

```
if let dic  = error?.userInfo {
   let errorString = dic[NSUnderlyingErrorKey]?.localizedDescription
   var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Oops!", message:errorString, delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
   alert.show()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you go in that direction, you should think very, very hard whether the NSError that you received is meant to be seen by a user. Many NSErrors are meant to be examined by a programmer only. In this case, "missing username" seems a strong indication that you, the programmer, made a mistake by sending a request without a username and shouldn't have done that in the first place. So showing an error alert may be the totally wrong solution.